# iOS 10.3.3 navigation bar not showing all buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have UINavigationBar with 3 buttons, which works fine on iPhone 7 with 11 iOS, but iPhone 5 10.3.3 showing only right of three buttons in it's nav bar.

What's wrong here?

```
    private func setupNavMenuButtons() {

    navButtonTimeframe.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeframeMenuHandler), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    navButtonTimeframe.setTitle(TIMEFRAMES[InAppProperties.sharedInstance.portfolioTimeframeMode], for: .normal)

    let timeframeBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navButtonTimeframe)

    let refreshNav = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(menuRefreshHandler))

    navButtonConvert.addTarget(self, action: #selector(convertMenuHandler), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    var image : UIImage
    switch InAppProperties.sharedInstance.convertSymbolWatch {
    case PreferencesHelper.BTC_SYMBOL:
        image = (UIImage(named: "convert_btc_portfolio")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))!
    case PreferencesHelper.ETH_SYMBOL:
        image = (UIImage(named: "convert_eth_portfolio")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))!
    default:
        image = (UIImage(named: "convert_usd_portfolio")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))!
    }

    navButtonConvert.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    let convertNav = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navButtonConvert)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [refreshNav, convertNav, timeframeBtn]
}
```

Comment: Try to debug the frame of buttons by setting `background color`.

Comment: Widths are diff in every screen, in small screen manage the button accordingly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong else your frames

Answer (score 1):

Added that line to two custom items (except .refresh):

```
 navButtonTimeframe.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40, height: 40)
```

And it's working.